# Wrap a Vue.js Firebase-Object into onAuthStateChanged handler?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vue-router

I'm implementing a Vue.js Web-Applikation with GoogleFirebase and the Vuefire plugin for firebase. I have to wrap The Vue.js Firebase-Object into the Firebase onAuthStateChanged function to get data from the realtime-database by the logged in users uid. The login is implemented with Vue-Router. The following Code should explain my question and I hope that somebody could help me with my question.

This is not working and I'm getting UID Of Null error.

```
firebase: {
    tableTennisData: db.ref(auth.currentUser.uid).child('tableTennis'),
},
```

This function, called through a Button logs the correct user id into the console.

```
methods: {
    test: function(){
        console.log(auth.currentUser.uid);
        this.uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
    },
}
```

But if this is working without the "onAuthStateChanged" handler, why is the implementation with the Firebase-Object not working?

This is how I push data to firebase and this is working very well due to the "onAuthStateChanged" handler out of the firebase Cloud-functions.

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (){
   db.ref(auth.currentUser.uid).child('tableTennis').push(obj);
});
```

**I really need a way to access the pushed data by the users uid. I think we could solve the error with the Firebase-Object wrapped into the "onAuthStateChanged" handler.**

To sum up the information, this is the login functionality of The Vue-Router file.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) =>{
  const currentUser = auth.currentUser;
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

  if(requiresAuth && !currentUser){
    next('/login');
   }else if(!requiresAuth && currentUser){
     next('/home');
  }else{
    next();
  }
});
export default router;
```

And finally, this is the main.js file.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import firebase from "firebase";
import './firebase';

import { rtdbPlugin } from 'vuefire'
Vue.use(rtdbPlugin);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let app = '';

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() =>{
  if(!app){
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
  }
});
```

Another firebase.js file exports the variables auth which is equal to firebase.auth() and db which is the same as firebase.database.

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase';

  const firebase = initializeApp({
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
  });

  export const db = firebase.database();
  export const auth = firebase.auth();
```

API-Information was deleted for this question.

I hope these are enough informations to help me solving this problem.

Thank you.

```
firebase: {
    tableTennisData: db.ref(auth.currentUser.uid).child('tableTennis'),
},
```

Error UID Of Null.

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe with how you configured and initialized firebase.

Its better to use progressive enhancement, so you can access the services you need when you need them.

Change your `firebase.js` config file to the following

```
// Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and
// must be listed before other Firebase SDKs
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";

// Add the firebase services that you want to use
import "firebase/database";
import "firebase/auth";

// Initialize firebase
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: "",
    appId: "",
    measurementId: ""
};

const fb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.database();

// export firebase services
export { db, fb };
```

Next change your `main.js` to the following

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import { fb } from "firebase"; // your firebase services live here (auth)
require("firebase/database"); // !important

import { rtdbPlugin } from 'vuefire'
Vue.use(rtdbPlugin);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

let app = '';

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() =>{
  if(!app){
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount("#app");
  }
});
```

Next change your route guarding logic in your router file to the following

```
import { fb } from "../firebase.js";
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

// check if route requiresAuth
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(rec => rec.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    const user = fb.auth().currentUser;
    // check auth state of user
    if (user) {
      next(); // user signed in, proceed to route
    } else {
      next('/login'); // user not signed in, route to login
    }
  } else {
    next(); // route does not require auth
  }
});

export default router;
```

Finally you should be able access to access the uid like so

```
firebase: {
    tableTennisData: db.ref(fb.auth().currentUser.uid).child('tableTennis'),
}
```

Remember `fb` now contains your firebase services and `db` now refers to your chose database (firestore/rtdb).

So you would access you firebase services like so

```
fb.auth()
fb.storage()
fb.analytics()
```

And you would access you rtdb like so

```
db.ref.('/users/' + uid)
```

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. I'll try this out. But do you also think it is curious that I can Call "auth.currentUser.uid" in a function and not in the Firebase-Object? Do you can explain this?

Comment: not sure why, but check out this documentation => https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#app. For the auth interface, the docs say do not call this constructor directly. Instead, use firebase.auth(). So i guess calling auth.someobject gives us some issues.

Comment: This makes sense to me. Thanks for your answers.